# grouping, splitting, and counting rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

given this table and data:

```
DECLARE @Table table (RowID int, RowCode char(1), RowValue int);set nocount on
INSERT @Table VALUES ( 6,'A',3757 )
INSERT @Table VALUES ( 5,'A',37827)
INSERT @Table VALUES (14,'A',48411)
INSERT @Table VALUES ( 1,'A',48386)
INSERT @Table VALUES (20,'A',48450)
INSERT @Table VALUES ( 7,'A',46155)
INSERT @Table VALUES (13,'A',721  )
INSERT @Table VALUES ( 2,'A',49335)
INSERT @Table VALUES (15,'A',4700 )
INSERT @Table VALUES (19,'A',64416)
INSERT @Table VALUES ( 8,'A',27246)
INSERT @Table VALUES (12,'B',54929)
INSERT @Table VALUES (16,'B',3872 )
INSERT @Table VALUES ( 3,'C',728  )
INSERT @Table VALUES (11,'C',1050 )
INSERT @Table VALUES ( 9,'C',3191 )
INSERT @Table VALUES (17,'C',866  )
INSERT @Table VALUES ( 4,'C',838  )
INSERT @Table VALUES (10,'D',550  )
INSERT @Table VALUES (18,'D',1434 );set nocount off
```

I need this:

```
                       VVVVVVVV
RowID RowCode RowValue RowChunk
----- ------- -------- --------
1     A       48386    1       
2     A       49335    1       
5     A       37827    1       
6     A       3757     1       
7     A       46155    1       
8     A       27246    2       
13    A       721      2       
14    A       48411    2       
15    A       4700     2       
19    A       64416    2       
20    A       48450    3       
12    B       54929    4       
16    B       3872     4       
3     C       728      5       
4     C       838      5       
9     C       3191     5       
11    C       1050     5       
17    C       866      5       
10    D       550      6       
18    D       1434     6
```

RowChunk starts at 1 and is incremented by 1 for each RowCode change and/or when there have been 5 of the same RowCode values.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, stumped? I was messing with `CEILING(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RowCode ORDER BY RowCode,RowID)/5.0)` but that's not right

Comment: Want someone to build it for you? Then post on rentacoder.com  For a brand new account to address me, more & more obvious your a leech.

Comment: Why do you need this to be done on the server? This kind of stuff is easily done in a "regular" programming language, on the client side or in a report. As I see it, the job of SQL Server is to give you the rows you need ordered by `RowCode` and the client takes over from there to calculate `RowChunk`. There might be reasons this should be done in SQL Server and depending on the reason there are perhaps different solutions.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson, I need a single update that will do this on a set of rows, it would be two cumbersome to interact with the application to do this. My answer below will easily convert into an update.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, must be a bunch of leeches around here, I see lots of code in answers. I guess "73.6k" is high and you can act however you want, so thanks for nothing. I hope you are happy I was able to solve my own question "leech-free". just remind me to bow down next time out paths meet, I wouldn't want to upset you again...

Comment: @RacerX: Yes, a good reason is to update a table somewhere with that information. Going external is not what you want in that case. I see that you solved it without a loop and that is almost always the best alternative.

Comment: My rep requires me to answer your question?  Get over yourself.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, you said `What have you tried?` implying (like from your other comment) `your a leech` Wow, thanks. Your rep allows you to say: `...For a brand new account to address me...` so how did I address you? I said `stumped?` and you start calling me a leech. I put forth a nice question to something I was working on. I even included some code in my comment to show I was trying to solve it, yet you still call me a leech. You have as much nerve as you have rep. If you don't want to answer, go do something else, go view another question, just leave your snide leech comments somewhere else.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, can you explain why I'm a leech? or even what I did to cause you to say that?

Comment: @OMG Ponies, I just find it hard to believe that you can call me a leach, yet continue to answer all the questions that your do here on SO. Why are those people not leeches as well? Perhaps you are mad that I said `stumped?` I guess you didn't like that, I should have added ;-) I ment no offense. Just because I create a new id when I come here, doesn't mean that I am a troll or a leech. I don't care about the rep. you shouldn't treat people with no rep or new ids like leeches. You have high rep, but showed your true self.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, you can reply like you have before `Troll harder?` but it won't change the fact that you acted in a mean spirit here, and won't answer what I did to get the `leech` and `troll` labels. You may handle lots of questions here so each isnt that important, but to people that don't ask many questions, each is important. for you to stomp on me, it isn't nice. you need to be more careful in your accusations, and realize that they are more than just words on a screen. to me, on this question, you have poorly represented SO and what it is all about. you don't have to reply. I'm done now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically my solution uses the same approach as yours, only with slightly different devices employed.

```
WITH NumberedRows AS (
  SELECT
    RowID,
    RowCode,
    RowValue,
    CodeChunk = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RowCode ORDER BY RowID) - 1) / 5
  FROM @Table
)
SELECT
  RowID,
  RowCode,
  RowValue,
  RowChunk = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY RowCode, CodeChunk)
FROM NumberedRows
```

Comment: Thank you too for the interesting question!

Comment: I was circling over the same solution, but i didn't think to use row_number(). I played only with rank and dense_rank. Great code:)

Comment: I hope you don't feel I'm being a leech like another member of SO does.

Comment: @Verrigo: Thanks! My level of expertise didn't let me see it to be so short at first. (I was expecting it to take more CTEs.) So, at first it was an interesting exercise, but in the end it became pure fun. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an analysis function, or any reasonable combination of such, which will address this.  You'll have to do it RBAR with a cursor or, slightly faster in my experience, a loop.

This example of looping assumes that RowID is unique.  If RowID is not the clustered PK, this will be very slow, so if that's the case you'll want to create a temp table.

```
DECLARE @RowID         INT = (SELECT MIN(RowID) FROM @Table)
DECLARE @MaxRowID      INT = (SELECT MAX(RowID) FROM @Table)
DECLARE @RowCode       CHAR(1)
DECLARE @LastRowCode   CHAR(1)
DECLARE @RowValue      INT
DECLARE @Chunk         INT = 0
DECLARE @RecsThisChunk INT
DECLARE @Results       TABLE (RowID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, RowCode     CHAR(1) NOT NULL, RowValue INT NOT NULL, Chunk INT NOT NULL)

WHILE @RowID <= @MaxRowID
    BEGIN
    -- Handle gaps in RowID
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Table WHERE RowID = @RowID) GOTO EndOfLoop

    -- Load values for this record
    SELECT @RowCode = RowCode, @RowValue = RowValue FROM @Table WHERE RowID = @RowID

    IF @LastRowCode IS NULL OR @RowCode <> @LastRowCode OR @RecsThisChunk = 5
        BEGIN
        -- Start a new chunk
        SET @Chunk = @Chunk + 1
        SET @RecsThisChunk = 1
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        -- Same chunk
        SET @RecsThisChunk = @RecsThisChunk + 1
        END

    SET @LastRowCode = @RowCode

    INSERT INTO @Results (RowID, RowCode, RowValue, Chunk) VALUES (@RowID, @RowCode, @RowValue, @Chunk)

    EndOfLoop:
    SET @RowID = @RowID + 1
    END

SELECT * FROM @Results
```

You may have tweak this a bit for 2005, I use 2008 routinely and don't recall all the little differences.

FYI, the results you show don't quite match the sample data.

Hope this helps!  The only alternative I see is a cursor, or handling this in the application layer.

Comment: the results match the data, you are ordering by RowID, where you should be ordering by RowCode+RowID

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer you are looking for :

```
create Table [table] (RowID int, RowCode char(1), RowValue int)
INSERT [Table] VALUES ( 6,'A',3757 ) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES ( 5,'A',37827) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES (14,'A',48411) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES ( 1,'A',48386) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES (20,'A',48450) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES ( 7,'A',46155) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES (13,'A',721  ) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES ( 2,'A',49335) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES (15,'A',4700 ) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES (19,'A',64416) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES ( 8,'A',27246) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES (12,'B',54929)
INSERT [Table] VALUES (16,'B',3872 )
INSERT [Table] VALUES ( 3,'C',728  ) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES (11,'C',1050 ) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES ( 9,'C',3191 ) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES (17,'C',866  ) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES ( 4,'C',838  ) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES (10,'D',550  ) 
INSERT [Table] VALUES (18,'D',1434 ) 


IF object_id('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #tempTable
END

CREATE TABLE #tempTable
(RowID int, RowCode char(1), RowValue int,RowChunk int)

INSERT INTO #tempTable
select RowID,RowCode,RowValue,null from [table] 


declare @RowId int
declare @RowCode char(1)
declare @Count int
declare @CurrentCode char(1)
declare @CountCurrent int

set @Count=1
set @CurrentCode=1
set @CountCurrent=0


DECLARE contact_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT RowID,RowCode FROM [table]

OPEN contact_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor into @RowId,@RowCode
set @CurrentCode=@RowCode
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  if(@CurrentCode=@RowCode)

  begin
    if(@CountCurrent=5)
    begin
      set @CountCurrent=1
      set @Count=@Count+1
      update #tempTable set RowChunk=@Count where RowID=@RowID
    end
    else
    begin
      set @CountCurrent=@CountCurrent+1
      update #tempTable set RowChunk=@Count where RowID=@RowID
    end
  end

  else
  begin
    set @CurrentCode=@RowCode
    set @CountCurrent=1
    set @Count=@Count+1
    update #tempTable set RowChunk=@Count where RowID=@RowID
  end

  FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor into @RowId,@RowCode
END
CLOSE contact_cursor
DEALLOCATE contact_cursor 

select * from #tempTable
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

this does the trick without a loop:

```
;WITH NumberedRows AS (   
SELECT 
r.RowID, r.RowCode, r.RowValue, CEILING(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r.RowCode ORDER BY r.RowCode,r.RowID)/5.0) AS CodeRowChunk
FROM @Table  r
)
, AllChunks AS (
SELECT r.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowCode,CodeRowChunk) AS ChunkRowNumber
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
      RowCode, CodeRowChunk 
      FROM NumberedRows) r
)
SELECT
a.RowID, RowCode, a.RowValue,
(SELECT ChunkRowNumber FROM AllChunks c WHERE c.RowCode=a.RowCode and c.CodeRowChunk=a.CodeRowChunk) AS RowChunk
FROM NumberedRows  a
```